# Trying to delete unused AWS security groups using Python. Getting error 'ec2.ServiceResoource' object has no attribute 'delete_securitygroup'

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

Below is my code.  I'm not quite sure what to do with the very last bit, I don't think that is correct.  How would I take the list of security group IDs from the variable "unused_sgs" and add that to the "delete_security_group" call from boto3?

Thanks

```
import boto3

ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2') 

sgs = list(ec2.security_groups.all())
insts = list(ec2.instances.all())

all_sgs = set([sg.group_id for sg in sgs])
all_inst_sgs = set([sg['GroupName'] for inst in insts for sg in inst.security_groups])
unused_sgs = all_sgs - all_inst_sgs

print("Total SGs:", len(all_sgs))
print("SGS attached to instances:", len(all_inst_sgs))
print("Orphaned SGs:", len(unused_sgs))
print('Unattached SG names:', unused_sgs)

for group_id in unused_sgs:
        ec2.delete_security_group(group_id)
print("Deleted Unused Groups")
```

Answer (score 1):

[delete_security_group](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.delete_security_group) is a client method.

```
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2') 
client = boto3.client('ec2')

....
....
for group_id in unused_sgs:
  client.delete_security_group(GroupId=group_id)
```

Comment: Cool, thank you.  Now it appears I've messed something up with the key 'group_id'.  Python doesn't want to accept it as a keyword argument.

`delete_security_group() only accepts keyword arguments. `

Is it not going to use that for loop to go through each security group ID and delete one by one?  I'm guessing that there's probably a more in depth and complicated way of writing this but I was hoping to avoid that.

Comment: @RaptorPete did you try to look at the link I provided for `delete_security_group`? It has everything you need. I have updated the answer that takes kwargs.

Answer (score 0):

The answer provided by helloV was correct. I had to update the delete_security_group command to use the client method.  I also had to use kwargs to get it to work properly.
Thanks for the assist.